# how to add user to team to admin page

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I can’t understand how to implement adding a user to Team on the admin page.
I wrote the add method in the controller, I can’t understand how to show it all in the interface.
Need two lists, one list of all Teams and a second list of all users and then save?
began to learn thymeleaf and a lot of strange things.

admin.html

```
 </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Admin page </h1>

    <!--
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/admin}" th:object="${team}" method="post">
        <p>Add Team: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="addTeam" />

    </form>
    -->

    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>


    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Users

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="users")
    public class Users {
        @Id
        @Column(name="email",unique = true, nullable = false,length = 200)
        String email;

        @Column(name="name",nullable = false,length = 200)
        String name;

        @Column(name="password",nullable = false,length = 128)
        @JsonIgnore 
        String password;


        @Column(name = "avatar", nullable = true)
        String avatar;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="team_id", nullable=true)
        Team team;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="role", nullable=false)
        @JsonIgnore        
        Role role;

        public Users() {
        }

         get und set
    }
```

Team

```
 Entity
    @Table(name="team")
    public class Team  {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
        Long id;

        @Column
        String name;

        @Column
        String url;

        @Lob
        @Column(name = "avatar",nullable = true,columnDefinition="BLOB")
        String avatar;


        @OneToMany(mappedBy="team",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JsonIgnore
        Set<Users> users = new HashSet<>();

        public Team() {
        }
     get und set
```

AdminController

@Controller//RestController
        public class AdminController {

```
    .....

     @GetMapping("/admin/team")
        List<Team> allTeams() {
          return teamRepository.findAll();
        }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/team/{id}/user/{email}", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
        public Users addUserToTeam(
                @PathVariable long id,@PathVariable String  email)  {
                Team team = teamRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchTeamException("Team not found"));
                Users user = userRpRepository.findById(email).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchUserException("User not found"));
                user.setTeam(team);
                user  = userRpRepository.save(user);
            return user;




 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String adminPage(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("admin",new Team());
            return "admin";
        }
            }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic . Petclinic is a good starting point to learn how a "classic" spring server-side rendered application works. It uses Spring Boot 2.2 and thymeleaf. Your question is imho to broad to answer it with; your post should return a new `View` or redirect to a GET and should not return the `User` entity.

Comment: I would like on the admin page I could select a user that already exists and select Team. Then by clicking the add button I add this user to this team.

Answer (score 0):

Ideologically from RMDB structure, the better way is creating the linkage table between User and Team.

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "email", length = 200) //@Id controls nullable and unique
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 128)
    @JsonIgnore 
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "avatar", nullable = true)
    private String avatar;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) //by default fetch - LAZY
    @JoinTable(name = "user_team", joinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_team__user"), nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_team_team"), nullable = false))
    private Set<Team> teams;
}
```

Team

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String url;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "avatar", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "BLOB")
    private String avatar;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) //by default fetch - LAZY
    @JoinTable(name = "user_team", joinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_team__team"), nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_team_user"), nullable = false))
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

UserTeam

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_team", uniqueConstraints =
        @UniqueConstraints(columnNames = {"user_id", "team_id"}, name = "uniq_some")
public class UserTeam {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id; //it's easier to create new Long Id key then composite key with user_id and team_id

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_team__user"), nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_team__team"), nullable = false)
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false) //I don't see Role entity but think it has id field
    @JsonIgnore  
    private Role role;
}
```

With this structure, you can get all users for the Team and all teams for the User. Collections are lazy so you need to use @Transactional, for example, for appropriate service methods.

And this structure is bi-directional: if you add new User into users collection in Team object, JPA will create new User. But ... linkage table contains one more required field `role_id`, so on such addition you will get an exception. So better first create User and Team objects, and after that create UserTeam linkage object with required Role (or set default Role and all new objects will be created with this Role).